# Reprojecting hypertile image from GDA94/Zone 55 to flat planar image

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, state-plane

I have setup Hypertiles to use the GDALCompress batch file to mosaic my image. This is all good so far but the coordinate systems they have available do not allow me to download an image to a planar coordinate system.

I have used the GDA94/Zone 55 coordinate system as this is the appropriate one for our location but I now need to reproject my image to a planar system.

How do I set up GDALwarp to do this?

I am not familiar with the command line switches and syntax that is used. I also know that there is a scale factor of 0.996 applied to my image. Perhaps this has to be changed to 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing a key point to your question but it looks like you can just do

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:28355 -t_srs epsg:xxxxx ...
```

where xxxx is whatever projection you want for the output. See http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html for details of all the available options.

If all you require is reporjection then I'd use gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html